# How can I change states in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, states

I m new at Angular so please forgive me for this question. But i didnt find a way to solve it. I have two main states and these states has child states.

```
$stateProvider

    .state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "views/login.html"
})

.state('login.intro', {
    url: "/intro",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "views/intro.html",
            controller: "introController"
        }
    }
})

.state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "views/menu.html"
})

.state('app.main', {
    url: "/main",
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "views/main.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        }
    }
})
```

I m trying redirect to app.main state when i m in login.intro state with this code.

```
$scope.startApp = function () {
    $state.go('/app/main');
};
```

But i m getting this error

Error: Could not resolve '/app/main' from state 'login.intro'
    at Object.transitionTo

So can you help me to fix this problem please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`$state.go()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go) expects the name of a state:

```
$state.go('app.main');
```

Comment: This answer is also answer of the question why i didn't find the solution on web. Thank you so much @JB Nizet. Working perfect :)